# What is the AD Trust Setting "foresttrans crossorg"

Tags: active-directory, migration, windows-domain

from nltest at a client with an issue root browsing to a sub-domain
`(NT 5) (Direct Outbound) (Direct Inbound) ( Attr: foresttrans crossorg )`

Answer (score 1):

> What is the AD Trust Setting “foresttrans crossorg”

Using some back of the napkin logic **foresttrans crossorg** stands for Forest Transitive Cross‐Organizational

Windows Server 2003 introduced the ability to configure cross-organizational to either be Transitive (Forest Trust) or Non-Transitive (External Trust).  Before this introduced an Active Directory could only be configured as non-transitive.

> One of the important features of Windows Server 2003 was that Microsoft finally achieved the ability to create a true Kerberos trust between forests, also called a "cross-forest trust." This was noticeably missing in Windows 2000 Server, which allowed only NTLM or "external" trusts that did not have transitivity.
>
> [image]

Source: [How to create a cross-forest trust in Active Directory](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-create-a-cross-forest-trust-in-Active-Directory)